# Cross compile SQLite for ARM

Tags: cross-compilation

I am using SQLite 3 for Database management in my ARM9 based microprocessor.

I want to cross compile the latest version of the SQLite 3 for my project in Linux (Ubuntu 10.04). I am using the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler` for development.

I tried to cross compile using following commands,

Downloaded the `sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.0.tar`
I extract it and then write the following command on Terminal,

```
sudo ./configure --exec-prefix=/media/8CCC8E9BCC8E7F68/SQLIte3/sqliteinstall/  --host=arm --target=arm CC=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar STRIP=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip RANLIB=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="-Os"
```

It successfully cross compiled the SQLite.

Then,

```
sudo make
```

command.

It successfully run. Now `make install` command.

It did not give me an error but when I went to the config.log file i found there is some sentences as following,

```
 1.conftest.c:17:7: error: size of array 'off_t_is_large' is negative
 2.conftest.c:12:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
 3.conftest.cpp:23:28: error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 4.conftest.c:67:13: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

I doubt that weather it has been cross compiled properly or not.
I can not understand.

I inserted the library on my board it works fine but the problem is that the speed got very slow. I think there is some problem that i have not set any flags for the GCC compiler.

I could not find any options.How I can set the particular flags for the GCC compiler so that unnecessary features can be omitted.

Comment: I think there is some issue that it can not find the compiler path ,So i find where my GCC compiler is installed and then reconfigured it with the following command.               ./configure --host=arm CC=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar STRIP=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip RANLIB=/opt/arm-2011.03/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib CFLAGS="Os"

Comment: But it gave me an error : C Compiler cannot create executables.

Comment: Right now I am getting an error in the cross compilation. It gave me an error that "C COMPILER CANNOT CREATE EXECUTABLES"

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is: don't add this to the comments. Edit the question itself such that it reflects exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Hey I got some useful information about the Cflags and Finally Configueed my SQLIte 3.7.15.2 with the Most appropriate parameters and features. Please go through the Below link for CFALGS.                                                                                                                                      http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: If I have to guess, your only problem is using sudo where is not necessary. Use `./configure` and `make` without `sudo` and use `sudo make install` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (and it works to cross compile most other third-party software):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:<path to directory containing your cross-compiler binaries>
$ cd <path to the directory containing the thirdparty code>
$ ./configure --prefix="<installation path>" --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
```

Add your CFLAGS and other configuration parameters to the configuration parameters. E.g.,

```
$ ./configure --prefix="<installation path>" --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi -CFLAGS="-Os" --enable-threadsafe
```

If in your case the target system is specified by arm-none-linux-gnueabi, replace the host in the above example:

```
$ ./configure --prefix="<installation path>" --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi -CFLAGS="-Os" --enable-threadsafe
```

The paths to GCC, CC, AR, ... will be found from the host you've set.